# IPtables and Remote Desktop with Proxy

Tags: iptables, proxy, remote-desktop, virtualbox, port-forwarding

So I setup a windows 2008 web server R2 on VirtualBox.

Currently using Bridged Network.

I can remote desktop to the machine hosting the VM (10.0.0.183)
but cannot remote desktop to the VM itself (10.0.0.195).

The remote port on the VM set to 5003.
VM setup to accept remote connections (windows side).

We also use a proxy for our internet, and I added these rules under NAT.
(centOS 5) on our proxy box.

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
-A REROUTING -i ppp0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5003
-A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.195 --dport 5003 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

I've been trying for hours and hours and just cannot get it to work.

I also used freedns so that we can use a domain name to connect too this VM over the internet. (the DNS points to our external IP address).

If we don't get this right we will have to purchase a PPoE from an ISP to connect to this VM remotely, but I know that there is an alternative route if I can just get this port forwarding right!

Comment: can you... - ping 10.0.0.195 from 10.0.0.183? ping 10.0.0.195 from any remote host? establish a remote desktop connection to 10.0.0.195 from 10.0.0.183? Also - what have you done to set 5003 as the remote desktop port?

Comment: Alternatively: can you use [SSH port forwarding](http://theillustratednetwork.mvps.org/Ssh/RemoteDesktopSSH.html) from a connection to your CentOS box to 10.0.0.195:5003 to establish a RDP connection?

Comment: I wonder if the bridging link goes through iptables.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the situation, I'll the machine hosting the virtualbox as the router.

The `REDIRECT` on the second line states all connections going past the router to be redirected to the router itself. This is probably not what you want.

If you put:

> -A PREROUTING -i ppp0 -p tcp --dport 5003 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.195

then all connections to `10.0.0.183 port 5003` would be forwarded to `10.0.0.195 port 5003`.
You might also need:

> -A POSTROUTING -d 10.0.0.195 -j SNAT

to make sure the reply packets come back to the router. You might also need some `FORWARD` entries to make it is allowed and possibly `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Comment: another way to do it would be to run tcpforward, dual netcats or localhost-ssh to forward the connection to "external" host.

Comment: @HopelessN00b  Thanks. My english ain't perfect.